# Seeing MAMP site over LAN

Tags: apache-http-server, lan, mamp

I've googled. I've posted at the MAMP site. Still no luck.

I have MAMP Pro running just fine. I go to another computer in the house and, not so good.
When I go to http://192.168.1.100:8888/wordpress/ I see text for the site, but the graphics don't load at all. Any click sends to http://mysitename:8888/wordpress/link and an error message (from the browser itself, it looked external)

FWIW - I am on a Snow Leopard Mac Pro, and just trying to see the one site from other machines in the house. I got this far, but now need an "idiot's guide" to move along.

Comment: FWIW - I checked this stack to make sure that MAMP questions are appropriate here, and I see a number of them that appear simpler than mine. (Like multiple sites, yes I can run many under the one MAMP install, no issue) A courtesy would be to comment for a downvote.

Comment: @Joe [SF] is for IT Professionals **only**. [SU], [unix.se], [wordpress.se], and [webmasters.se] would be more appropriate for your questions.

Comment: Got it. Sorry, I found the stack and first searched for my answer. I failed to check the FAQ, which is what I should have done. The move is much appreciated.